# Why does DLL_THREAD_DETACH happen twice?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, com, dllmain

I am learning COM. I wrote a simple COM component in the DLL and registered it in the registry. Then I created a simple client and tried to use my COM component. But I don't understand the `DllMain` behaviour (I read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also).

```
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  _In_ DWORD     fdwReason,
  _In_ LPVOID    lpvReserved){
  pDll = hinstDLL;
  if (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH == fdwReason){
    trace("DllMain(): DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH");
  }
  else if (DLL_THREAD_ATTACH == fdwReason){
    trace("DllMain(): DLL_THREAD_ATTACH");
  }
  else if (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH == fdwReason){
    trace("DllMain(): DLL_PROCESS_DETACH");
  }
  else if (DLL_THREAD_DETACH == fdwReason){
    trace("DllMain(): DLL_THREAD_DETACH");
  }
  else{
    trace("DllMain(): unknown variant...");
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

I expected for each `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` one `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` to be called and for each `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` one `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` to be called (if the exception doesn't happen).

But I see for a single `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` there are two `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`:

[image]

Why does it happen?

Comment: Curiously, if you had read the documentation of `DllMain` as you say you did, you should have these questions answered already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` :

> Note that a DLL's entry-point function is called with this value only by threads created after the DLL is loaded by the process. When a DLL is loaded using LoadLibrary, existing threads do not call the entry-point function of the newly loaded DLL.

There is no relation between the number of `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` and `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. It's all about loading and creation time. When a thread is created while a DLL is loaded, `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` will be called. When a thread exits while a DLL is loaded, `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` will be called. A thread will never be preempted by a DLL, so the THREAD calls can only happen at creation and end of a thread.

In you case, the log only says that you didn't create a thread after loading the DLL, but two thread exited before unloading the DLL.

Comment: ... and yes, this makes DLL_THREAD_ATTACH mostly useless, particularly in combination with the other limitations of DllMain.  But there are edge cases. :-)